# Extracting only text form String in Java

Tags: java

I have got string like str = Adobe Flash Player 11.4.402.287 (11.3 MB), I need to extract only Adobe Flash Player as the output. Pls suggest..

I tried using Regex like :

```
String str = "Adobe Flash Player 11.4.402.287 (11.3 MB)";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+([0-9]+).*");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
```

Comment: Use regular expressions.

Comment: am not sure which regular expression to use..

Comment: Use `"[\\p{L}\\s]+"`. Now let's wait and see if someone makes this suggestion into his own answer :)

Comment: @BuiAkinori. How exactly would that return `Adobe Flash Player`?

Comment: @RohitJain Hardly, since it wouldn't even compile :)

Comment: sry sry str = str.Substring(0,19);

Comment: @BuiAkinori: How about this ?? String str = "Adobe Flash Player" ;)

Comment: @bi0s.kidd0: Sound exactly :)

Comment: @BuiAkinori: No offense buddy. I probably thought the question was extracting some string from a [string] [number] format when the length was unknown.

Comment: @BuiAkinori. That would still not compile. It should be `substring` and not `Substring`.

Comment: thanks Marko Topolnik, it worked fine..

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by `@MarkoTopolink`, regexp `[\\p{L}\\s]+` helped me. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    String str = "Adobe Flash Player 11.4.402.287 (11.3 MB)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([a-zA-Z ]+)([0-9]+).*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

There are two problems in your try:

1. Grouping is done using `()`, you did not define a group for the text you actually wanted
2. You need to add a space to get more than one word.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
String str = "Adobe Flash Player 11.4.402.287 (11.3 MB)";
String [] strs = str.split("([ |0-9|.|(.*MB)]*) [ |0-9|.|(.*MB)]*");
for (String strng : strs) {
    System.out.println(strng.trim());
}
```

Comment: Horrible way to do simple stuff. I'll die figuring out, why someone would split a string like that.

Comment: Why on Earth do you want to match the exact character sequence "0-9"??